# What does %{ $_.Key1 } mean?

Tags: powershell, azure-hdinsight

While programming for HDInsight I came across lines like

```
$storageAccountKey = Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey 
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName 
    -Name $storageAccountName 
    |  %{ $_.Key1 }
```

I understand `$_` refers to the result of the `Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey` command. But what exactly is the meaning of `%{}` ?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`%{ $_.Key1 }` ⇔ `ForEach-Object { Write-Output $_.Key1 }` ⇔ for each object in the pipeline, echo the value of its property `Key1`.

`%` is an [alias](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847830.aspx) for [`ForEach-Object`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849731.aspx). `$_` is the current object [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In fact `$storageAccountKey=Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccountName |  %{ $_.Key1 }` only works for PowerShell 1.3.2 and previous versions.

The above command does **not** work now.

Please use the latest command like the bellow:

```
$storageAccountKey = Get-AzStorageAccountKey `
            -ResourceGroupName $storageAccountResourceGroupName `
            -Name $storageAccountName | Where-Object {$_.KeyName -eq "key1"} | %{$_.Value}
```