# Found this bit of PowerShell code and not sure what this variable processing does

Tags: powershell

Morning all,
Somewhat new to PS and ran into a line of code that I do not understand; Line of code is this:

```
$psData | %{‘{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}|{4}’ -f $[0],$[1],$[2],$[3],$_[4] } >> “c:\users\johna\Elements.txt”
```

The pipe append to an folder and filename is clearly understood, as well as the piping of the input “$psData” variable, but what I’ve not been able to find is a description of `%{‘{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}|{4}’ -f $[0],$[1],$[2],$[3],$_[4] }`
Looking at the content of the Elements.txt it seems clear that the 0-4 are four ‘|’ values, but like to understand how it works.

Thanks

Understand this code

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35272003/what-does-key1-mean. It looks to me that it's iterating over `psData` and does string formatting. It substitutes the placeholders with the corresponding values provided after `-f`. Also, I'm not sure if you can do indexing with `$[index]`, shouldn't it be `$index`? Does script work?

Comment: Hello Milo.  Yes, script does kind of work, as there is no error checking, but the output Elements.txt has each with the 5 values contained in $psData separated by a '|' symbol.  Not sure where you see the $index unless that is another explanation (new to PS) for ForEach cmdlet (that's what I'm told the % stands for

Comment: Your code is a little messed up. It is more likely this `$_[0],$_[1],$_[2],$_[3],$_[4]`, right?  ... with the underlines ... The number in square brackets is the index. 

Comment: ... and as already mentioned in th other forum you posted this question ... you may start your research here: [PowerShell Format operator `-f`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.4#format-operator--f) ... or here: [How to: The -f Format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html).

Comment: I wrote up an answer. If there are any mistakes, please say so I can correct it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with PS but I will try to explain it as best as I can. So...

1. We have `%` which is shorthand for `ForEach-Object`, which is used to iterate through each element of a collection (in this case, `$psData`). Inside the `%{}`, `$_` represents the current object being processed.
2. `$_[0], $_[1], $_[2], $_[3], $_[4]` represent values at given position (index). In this case, at indices 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.
3. What does `-f` do? The `-f` operator is used for string formatting. It substitutes the placeholders {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, and {4} with the corresponding values provided after `-f`. So it will replace `{0}` with `$_[0]` and `{1}` with `$_[1]` and so on.
4. After replacing you will get elements separated with `|` because that's how you defined it in template.

Comment: `${}` is not a shorthand for `ForEach-Object`, `%` is.

Comment: Typo. Corrected it.